# Error SDK location not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I cloned the project from gitHub to check the sample code on *segment.io*. After importing into the android studio I am getting the error

> Error:SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

I changed the SDK location in `local.properties` to my current SDK location which is

```
sdk.dir = /home/mobiefit/Android/Sdk
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: set your sdk path step by step and make sure sdk is completely downloaded

Answer (score 1):

There are only three ways to do it:

create `local.properties` file and have either `sdk.dir` or `android.dir` line.
have `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable defined.

While your Android Studio knows that the SDK is at that place, I doubt that Android Studio is passing that information to gradle and thus we're seeing that error.

You need to create local.properties file at the project root and put the following line and it should compile the code successfully.

ex `sdk.dir = /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/`

Comment: my local.properties file is already at the project root. I have followed the same project structure as my other projects have.

Answer (score 1):

while importing code this will come:

**Android Studio will use this Android SDK instead: 'F:\sdk' and will modify the project's local.properties file.**

then say ok..
that's all...