# Android SDK location not found with environment variable set

Tags: android, react-native, yarnpkg

I am developing a react native app using yarn and whenever I try to run my app on an android device, I get the following error:

```
SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'mobile/android/local.properties'.
```

The weird thing is that I have installed the sdk (using `brew install --cask android-sdk`) and set an export on my ./zshrc (using `export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk`) which gets correctly printed out to the screen if I type `echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` on my terminal.

To no avail, I have also tried a different approach I read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032828/error-sdk-location-not-found), which was to create a file named `local.properties` and set the variable there by doing something like `sdk.dir = /usr/local/share/android-sdk`.

Any ideas why gradle cannot properly find the sdk?

Answer (score 2):

```
Open the terminal and run the command: nano $HOME/.bashrc aggregate the follow line:

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Ctrl+o save and ctrl+x close.

And run the command:

source $HOME/.bashrc

echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```